# Comparison of String with ActiveSupport::Duration failed for time_ago_in_words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, activesupport

I get this error when I try to use `time_ago_in_words`:

```
Comparison of String with ActiveSupport::Duration failed
```

I'm trying to check whether an object was created more than 8 minutes ago:

```
  <% if time_ago_in_words(obj.created_at) > 8.minutes  %>
    <p>Yes</p>
  <% end %>
```

Would appreciate it if anyone knows the correct way to perform this test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`time_ago_in_words` returns a phrase meant to be used in your UI.  If you're comparing dates with each other, you're going to want to do it before it's translated into a user-friendly string.

Also note that I used `minutes.ago` in order to compare apples with apples.

```
<% if obj.created_at > 8.minutes.ago  %>
    Within the last 8 minutes
<% else %>
    Longer than 8 minutes ago
<% end %>
```